# Replicate function using list comprehension in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I came across this replicate function,

```
replicate' n x = [x|y <- [1..n]]
```

Why is y there? y is being assigned values from 1 to n despite not being featured in the output expression.

‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

Comment: Because whoever wrote that code didn't know that you could put the wildcard pattern `_` there. Having a `y` variable that's unused like that is just poor form.

Comment: You can also write `fmap (const x) [1..n]` or [`x <$ [1..n]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36-)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that the list comprehension:

```
[some_expr_involving_y | y <- [1..n]]
```

will produce a list of `n` elements that are the results of evaluating `some_expr_involving_y` with `y` set to each the numbers `1`, `2`, ... `n` in turn.

In the special case where `some_expr_involving_y` is just some constant `x` that doesn't depend on `y`, the result will be `n` copies of `x`, one for each (unused) value of `y`.

As pointed out in a comment, it may be better style to use a wildcard, as that's what it's for:

```
replicate' n x = [x | _ <- [1..n]]
```